# Mostrar el contenido de un archivo de texto en una sola linea en C

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente programa que lee el contenido de un archivo de texto.
¿Cómo puede hacer para que en la salida me muestre el contenido de ese archivo de texto en una sola línea?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

  FILE *pf;
  char archivo[81];

pf = fopen( "fichero1.txt", "r" );
  if ( pf != NULL ) {
    while ( fgets( archivo, 81, pf ) != NULL ) {
      printf("La variable archivo es:[%s]\n", archivo);
}
    fclose(pf);
  }
  else {
    fprintf( "Error" );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: creo que deberias de quitar `\n`

Comment: Concatenando el resultado de cada fgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Tengo el siguiente programa que lee el contenido de un archivo de texto. ¿Cómo puede hacer para que en la salida me muestre el contenido de ese archivo de texto en una sola línea?

Asumamos que el archivo tiene lo siguiente:

```
Pepe
Dave
Jose
```

Entonces, al momento de ejecutar tu código, sale lo siguiente:

```
La variable archivo es [Pepe
]
La variable archivo es [Dave
]
La variable archivo es [Jose
]
```

**¿Por qué salió ese resultado?**

El problema radica en el funcionamiento de la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Ya que la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) incluirá el salto de línea (`\n`) en la cadena leída. Por esa razón los nombres como Pepe, Dave, Jose, tendrán un salto de línea al final.

**Solución:** Debemos eliminar ese salto de línea para que nos imprima todo en una sola línea:

```
while (fgets( archivo, 81, pf ) != NULL ) 
{
    archivo[strlen(archivo) - 1] = '\0';
    printf("La variable archivo es:[%s]\n", archivo);
}
```

Lo único que se debe hacer es obtener la longitud de la cadena y restarle -1 para que nos dé la posición del salto de línea.

En pantalla nos daría lo siguiente:

```
La variable archivo es [Pepe]
La variable archivo es [Dave]
La variable archivo es [Jose]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que quitar `\n` ya que este lo que hace es agregar un salto de linea.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main (void) {

      FILE *pf;
      char archivo[81];

    pf = fopen( "fichero1.txt", "r" );
      if ( pf != NULL ) {
        while ( fgets( archivo, 81, pf ) != NULL ) {
          printf("La variable archivo es:[%s]", archivo);
    }
        fclose(pf);
      }
      else {
        fprintf( "Error" );
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Prueba lo y me cuentas cualquier cosa,

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: He hecho la modificación que me has dicho pero me siguen apareciendo saltos de linea quitando el \n